# #VALUE Error on Custom Function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-udf

```
Function HasStrike(Rng as Range) As Boolean
HasStrike = Rng.Font.Strikethrough
End Function
```

I am using a custom function to see if a column has a strikethrough. If the column has a strikethrough, it returns a boolean and I delete the row. However, I am getting a #VALUE error. The column I am checking only has the word "MASS" in it. Not sure what's going on.

[image: User Screenshot]

Comment: Does it work if you check one cell?  Under what case does it fail?  Can you show some screenshot examples?

Comment: Yes, it has worked before. I'm running a VB macro that ties to the boolean.

Comment: Are you calling the function on a single cell or on a group of cells?

Comment: Calling the function on a single cell.

Comment: @kmiao91 used the function in a new workbook, no errors..

Comment: @bsapaka You're right, it shouldn't return an error. but it is.

Comment: Which is why I asked for screenshots of some content.  Otherwise this is not reproducible.

Comment: @kmiao91 did you try it in a new/blank workbook? Is the function in a module and not a sheet? Seconded that we need more info

Comment: http://imgur.com/2n9Uupw,1VkbYXz#1
I am pulling the cell from any column in image 1
Function is indeed in a module since it is a custom function.

Comment: Where are you using the function?  Is it a `Public Function`?

Comment: In the second image, I'm using it in Column C

Comment: What is the code calling it?  Are you passing it a single cell Range or something else?

Comment: I have the function in one cell. It calls it from another cell in a separate worksheet. Then it does it for the entire column, cell by cell by dragging the formulas down.

Answer (score 0):

Your function will return #VALUE if the cell content has mixed formatting: some text is struck out and some not.

Select one of the "problem" input cells and go to the "Format Cells" >> Font tab.  Is "Strikethrough" checked or does it look like below? That would indicate mixed formatting.

[image]

Try this maybe:

```
Function HasStrike(Rng As Range) As Boolean
    Dim v
    Application.Volatile '<< EDIT: added this
    On Error Resume Next
    v = Rng.Font.Strikethrough
    On Error GoTo 0
    HasStrike = v Or IsNull(v)
End Function
```

Comment: Hmmm - It seems to have half worked. The function returns Boolean but the boolean isn't right. I'm getting false for cells that do have strikethroughs

Comment: You have to make sure to recalculate the function - it may not trigger a recalculation if you just change the formatting (or the VBA code for the function), since you didn't change the *value* of the input cell.  Maybe add `Application.Volatile` at the top of the function.